SQL Package extract command is failing in PowerShell script
I wrote a PowerShell script that uses SQL Package to create a dacpac and apply it to my local db.  This script worked fine and I was getting ready to share it and it started throwing an error.
An unexpected failure occurred: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices' threw an exception..

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SqlSchemaModelStaticState' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlCoreAnnotationRegister.RegisterModelAnnotations(ModelSchema storeSchema)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlSchemaModel.SqlSchemaModelStaticState.RegisterModelSchema()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlSchemaModel.SqlSchemaModelStaticState..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlSchemaModel.SqlSchemaModelStaticState.get_ModelSchema()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlSchemaModel.InitializeModelSchema()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.DoExtractDacpacOperation(CommandLineArguments parsedArgs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.PerformAction(CommandLineArguments parsedArgs)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.Main(String[] args)

Nothing in my environment was changed.  The possible exception is I installed VS 2022 (community), with SSDT.  I just don't remember if it was between it running and not running.  However, I am running this script in PS on my local machine, not connected to any VS projects.
I've tried uninstalling VS.  I also reinstalled SQL Package.
Here is the script.  It throws the error when it calls the SQL Package at sqlpackage $arguments
$tableData = ""
$dacpacFile = "databasename.dacpac"
$outputPath = "./"
$config = Get-Content "$PsScriptRoot\DacpacToLocalDb.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
$sourceServer = $config.SourceServer
$sourceDatabase = $config.SourceDatabase
$targetServer = $config.TargetServer
$targetDatabase = $config.TargetDatabase

if($(Write-Host "Copy Data Also? Y / N:  " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green; Read-Host) -eq 'y')
{ 
    $tableData = "/p:ExtractAllTableData=True"
}

Write-Host "Generating Dacpac file..." -ForegroundColor Green
$sourceConnectionString = "Server=$sourceServer;Database=$sourceDatabase;Encrypt=False; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$arguments = "/Action:""Extract""", "/SourceConnectionString:""$sourceConnectionString""", "/TargetFile:""./$dacpacFile""", $tableData
sqlpackage $arguments

if($(Write-Host "Generate script? Y / N:  " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green; Read-Host) -eq 'y')
{
    Write-Host "Creating the SQL script..." -ForegroundColor Green
    $script = "$bin\$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($dacpacFile)).sql"
        $targetConnectionString = "Server=$targetServer;Database=$targetDatabase;Encrypt=False; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        $arguments = "/Action:Script", "/SourceFile:""$dacpacFile""", "/TargetConnectionString:""$targetConnectionString""", "/OutputPath:""./dacpacScript.sql"""
        $arguments+=$sqlCmdVariables
        & sqlpackage $arguments
}

if($(Write-Host "Publish to '$targetServer'? Y / N:  " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green; Read-Host) -eq 'y')
{
    Write-Host "Applying file to target db..." -ForegroundColor Green
    $targetConnectionString = "Server=$targetServer;Database=$targetDatabase;Encrypt=False; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    $arguments = "/Action:Publish", "/SourceFile:""./$dacpacFile""", "/TargetConnectionString:""$targetConnectionString""", "/p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Logins;ServerRoleMembership;ServerRoles;Credentials;Rolemembership;DatabaseRoles;Users", "/p:AdditionalDeploymentContributors=AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor", `
    "/p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorPaths= ./", "/p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments=SqlPackageFilter=IgnoreSchema(svc.solarwinds)"
    & sqlpackage $arguments
}



Here are some things to try or consider: Reinstall the Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom assembly by installing the correct version of SSDT or downloading it from the Microsoft NuGet Gallery. Ensure your environment variables include the necessary SQL Server assembly paths, as Visual Studio or SSDT changes can disrupt this. Add the assembly manually in your PowerShell script before calling sqlpackage with: Add-Type -Path 'C:\Path\To\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll'. Also, check for updates to SQLPackage, SSDT, and Visual Studio, as these may fix related issues.

I guess you have multiple sqlpackage versions installed in different paths. Try executing sqlpackage.exe with full path, not just exe name. ScriptDom.dll actual version is 16, not 12. Most recent sqlpackage release is 162.5. You can check which version is called by sqlpackage.exe /version

While both comments were invaluable, I think @IVNSTN's comment was closest to the case.  I set this problem aside for a couple days to work on getting an API project running in my local environment.  Since I had uninstalled VS during my troubleshooting, I had to reinstall it for the API project. (VS is not my team's IDE).  After that was done I went back to my script and it was working as expected.  I'm not sure what it fixed but I'll take it.
